# asyncio return "Task was destroyed but it is pending!"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm new in asynchronus programming. I'm triyng to write script that is used to check statuses of web pages.
And ofcourse I'd like doint thath asynchronus.
My snippet:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

url_site = 'http://anysite.com'
fuzz_file = 'fuzz.txt'


def generate_links(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return [str(url_site) + str(line.strip()) for line in f]

async def fetch_page(client, url):
    async with client.get(url) as response:
        return response.status

async def run():
    links = generate_links(fuzz_file)
    for f,link in asyncio.as_completed([fetch_page(client,link) for link in links]):
        print("[INFO] [{}] {}".format(f, link))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
conn = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxy="http://10.7.0.35:8080")
client = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=conn)
loop.run_until_complete(run())
client.close()
```

But I'm getting the next errors:`Task was destroyed but it is pending!`
Could someone to point me where I made mistake?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed):

> Return an iterator whose values, when waited for, are Future instances.

So you must `await` every object returned by `as_completed`:

```
for f in asyncio.as_completed([fetch_page(client,link) for link in links]):
    status = await f
```

You might also want to look into [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) for more fine grained control.

Comment: I'm not getting those errors. What version are using?

Comment: I use python 3.5, asyncio 3.4.3, aiohttp 0.19

Comment: So am I, but I'm not getting any errors; however, I'm not running a `ProxyConnector`, so maybe that's causing the issue? Also, close the event loop explicitly: `loop.close()`